# I need help finding a Swipe Gesture Swipe for Android, and a fix for my swipe and tap clashing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity, trying to build a Google AR App where you would tap and the character would do an animation. I'm trying to do a swipe as well, where on swipe it would do an animation as well. But I am not finding any proper code for swipe or any code that I understand, And I don't understand C# fully yet or even Unity, neither am I an avid coder, doing this for my internship. So I wonder if anyone can help me out?

```
public Animator anim;

public bool animBool;


public void Update()
{
    BoxingAnimation();        
}

public void BoxingAnimation()
{

    animBool = anim.GetBool("hasTapped");
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            if (animBool == false)
            {
                anim.SetBool("hasTapped", true);
            }
        }
    }
    if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Boxing"))
    {
        anim.SetBool("hasTapped", false);
    }
}
```

}

This is my On-Tap animation code. But my problem is that when I am doing a swipe, it will always read the first touch on the screen and nothing after. I need a way to make the tap happen only if the touch has moved a little on the x or y axis. 
But I know NOTHING and need help.

In another script I have it spawning the character in the AR Camera. It is set up so that it only spawns one. So any touch after that can be used for another function.

Answer (score 0):

When using touchphase there are multiple different modes this can be in. Ontop of this, when touches are made they are saved within a list which can be accessed so you can access each touch on the screen separately. Therefore, by checking if the touch mode is phased or just the normal tap you can use this to select which animation you would like.
I'm fairly new myself but that is what I've gathered so far.

Comment: Oh thank you. What I'm really asking is how I am to this, because I have a general knowledge on what I am trying to achieve.